# Why CakePHP set _method equal PUT instead POST

Tags: php, cakephp

I update recently my CakePHP project to 2.4.5.

Now, some `forms` set the *input hidden* = **PUT**. But, the `method` is POST.

I don't know why this is happened.

This is the form:

```
  <?php echo $this->Form->create('User', array('url' => array('action' => 'new_password', $this->request->data['User']['forget_password'], 'admin' => false), 'autocomplete' => 'off')) ?>

    <?php echo $this->Form->hidden('User.id') ?>

    <fieldset>
      <label class="block clearfix">
        <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
          <?php echo $this->Form->password('User.password', array('label' => false, 'div' => false, 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Digite a nova senha')) ?>
          <i class="icon-user"></i>
        </span>
      </label>

      <label class="block clearfix">
        <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
          <?php echo $this->Form->password('User.password_confirmation', array('label' => false, 'div' => false, 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Digite novamente a nova senha')) ?>
          <i class="icon-user"></i>
        </span>
      </label>

      <div class="space"></div>

      <div class="clearfix">
        <?php echo $this->Form->button('<i class="icon-key"></i> '. __('Enviar'), array('class' => 'width-35 pull-right btn btn-sm btn-success', 'escape' => false)) ?>
      </div>

      <div class="space-4"></div>
    </fieldset>
  <?php echo $this->Form->end() ?>
```

And, the action:

```
/**
 * new_password method
 *
 * @access public
 * @param String $forget_password
 * @return void
 * @since 1.0 
 * @version 1.0 
 * @author Patrick Maciel
 */
public function new_password($forget_password)
{

  $user = $this->User->findByForgetPassword($forget_password);

  if ($user == false) {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Link inválido'), 'flash/frontend/error');
    $this->redirect('/');
  }

  $this->layout = 'login';

  if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $this->User->set = $this->request->data;
    if ($this->User->validates(array('fieldList' => array('id', 'forget_password', 'password', 'password_confirmation')))) {

     // ...

    } else {

     // ...

    }
  }

  $user['User']['password'] = null;
  $this->request->data = $user;

}
```

## So...

- Why CakePHP do that?
- I can, if I change my method to validation `$this->request->is('put')` instead POST will work, but, I don't want do that. I want a POST, not a PUT.
- And I need to know, how and when CakePHP set PUT, POST or DELETE in an `input hidden form`.

**Obs.: I not force method, using `'type' => 'POST'` because, previously this is not need.**

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Do you have an actual problem, something being broken or not working or are you just wondering what it is?

Comment: Not working because, I validate if `$this->request->is('post')`, and not PUT. So, I have a situation here. But, I want to know, why cakephp do that?

Comment: Always use `if ($this->request->is(array('put', 'post'))` and done :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I can infer from the documentation, when you provide data to the view, and create a form based on this data, Cake assumes you want to edit the form, and so it makes it a "put" request.

The `PUT` method is something from REST services, and this method is associated with editing content, as opposed to `POST` method that is for insert new content. So Cake when sees the data being passed to the view, it interprets as editing it.

So if you want to receive this form by post, you have two options: change the form method by passing the option `'type' => 'post'`, or change on the controller by `if($this->request->is('put'))`

Check the documentation for more references:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#options-for-create

Answer (score 2):

Like Patrick said, when the `Request data` contains a Model.id `CakeRequest::method()` is set to `put`. The preferred way to handle this in cakephp would be as follows.

```
if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put')) {
    // Code
}
```

You can see this in [baked](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/code-generation-with-bake.html) controller, edit actions.

Comment: I never saw such behavour!!

Comment: That's because you have never used cake bake!!