# CakePhp2 Search form switches from post to not post, when searching for the primary key

Tags: forms, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

Today I found a totally weird behaviour and I would like to stop it.

I use CakePhp 2.9 and have a search form, with which I want to search orders. My primary key in the model is the session_id due to relations to other models.

```
class Order extends AppModel
{    
    public $primaryKey = 'session_id';
```

I open my search form with

```
    <?php echo $this->Form->create(
        'Order',
        array(
            'url' => array('controller' => 'orders', 'action' => 'search')
        )
    ); ?>
```

Which results in the following HTML:

```
<form id="OrderSearchForm" action="/orders/search" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

In the controller I do different things depending on the request being of the type post or not.
For debugging the weird behaviour I added the following debug lines in the controller:

```
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        debug('post');
    } else if ($this->request->is('get')) {
        debug('get');
    } else {
        debug($_REQUEST);
        debug($_GET);
        debug($_POST);
    }
```

So as long as i search for other values than the session_id of my Order or combine the session_id with other search values everything is fine. 
But as soon as I search ONLY for the session_id the generated HTML for the search form is changed to

```
<form id="OrderSearchForm" action="/orders/search/mysearchvaluesessionidstring" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

And when I then submit my form it is suddenly no longer considered as "post". The debug output for $_GET is still empty and the one for $_POST still filled, but the condition if ($this->request->is('post')) is not triggered anymore.

How can I change this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that cake is changing the request type to `PUT` when the request data only contains the session id.  You can get around this by checking `if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put')))` instead of just checking for `POST` requests.

You can read more about why this might be happening [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21240005/6326906)